# No ping to a multicast address from Windows

Tags: windows, ip-address, ping, multicast

On my computer, when I try to ping to a multicast address, none of them return a response.

On the other hand, there is a Unix server I know that does have ping to these addresses.

Is there a way to add a route from my computer to this one, so that I can use these addresses?

Comment: You're right, `ping` on Windows doesn't work with multicast addresses. That's because it discards broadcast pings. See RFC1122. Also see this question on Server Fault: [broadcast ping on windows LAN](http://serverfault.com/questions/110780/broadcast-ping-on-windows-lan).

Answer (score 2):

No, ICMP is not typically used with multicast because it is a prime source for DoS amplification.  Similarly multicast doesn't tend to be that useful as you need multicast enabled and configured routers to cross LAN segments.

See this answer if you are wanting to use multicast pings for discovery of local machines:

[Multicast Ping (Windows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632461/multicast-ping-windows/6012220#6012220)