# Multicast Ping (Windows)

Tags: windows, ping, multicast, autodiscovery

I am trying to implement server auto discovery so that clients will be able to see a list of servers available to connect to. I would like to auto discover servers even if they are in different subnets.

I have read that windows does not respond to broadcast ping, but is it possible to make all these servers to join a multicast group and use multicast ping on the group to see what servers are up?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zero configuration networking (Zeroconf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeroconf).

Note multiple LAN segments requires routers to be configured to route multicast traffic, they do not by default.  Similarly IGMP enabled switches are usually recommended for computer connectivity.